# Specify Ports for Ipykernel_launcher in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I would like to control the ports used by VSCode notebooks. It seems that VSCode (v1.77.3) launches Ipython kernels with a command like this:

```bash
/home/username/bin/python3.8 -m ipykernel_launcher --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9010 --control=9006 --hb=9005 --Session.signature_scheme="hmac-sha256" --Session.key=b"72dc9cca-e641-445a-9ceb-3ca5433dc8c0" --shell=9007 --transport="tcp" --iopub=9011 --f=/home/username/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-v2-3617206EN99MmVys9xf.json
```

There are four port numbers that get passed: `stdin`, `control`, `iopub` and `hb`(heartbeat). In my case these ports are generally assigned close to 9000.

How can I either set the ports independently or set a base port number for all four so that only port numbers greater than the base port are used?

I have tried searching Ipython and Jupyter related configuration in VSCode and the only relevant one I have found is:

```
    "jupyter.jupyterCommandLineArguments": [
    ]
```

I have tried setting individual ports, for example, with

```
    "jupyter.jupyterCommandLineArguments": [
        "--control=55555"
    ]
```

from the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63952039/490648 however that does not seem to have any impact.

This not seem to be documented in VScode anywhere. Is it at all possible to control the behavior from VSCode configuration?

Comment: is that using the VScode extension from Microsoft?

Comment: yes @gogasca v2023.3.1201040234